# Perl and Python difference in predeclaring functions

Tags: python, perl

#### Perl

```perl
 test();

 sub test {
   print 'here';
 }
```

#### Output

```
here
```

#### Python

```python
test()

def test():
   print('here')
   return
```

#### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythontest", line 2, in <module>
    test()
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

I understand that in Python we need to define functions before calling them and hence the above code doesn't work for Python.

I thought it was same with Perl but it works!

Could someone explain why is it working in the case of Perl?

Answer (score 7):

Perl uses a multi-phase compilation model. Subroutines are defined in an early phase before the actual run time, so no forward declarations are necessary.

In contrast, Python executes function definitions at runtime. The variable which holds a function must be assigned (implicitly by the `def`) before it can be called as a function.

If we translate these runtime semantics back to Perl, the code would look like:

```
# at runtime:
$test->();

my $test = \&test;

# at compile time:
sub test { print 'here' }
```

Note that the `$test` variable is accessed before it was declared and assigned.

Comment: Or to keep the calling syntax: `test(); *test = sub { print 'here'; };`.